# Matlab multiply rows of matrices - vectorized or bsxfun

Tags: matlab

I have 2 5000x10 matrices and I would like to get a length-5000 vector that has as entries the vector products of the corresponding rows in the two matrices. I.e. the first entry should be row1 of matrix1 * row1 of matrix2 transposed and so on.

I can implement this with a for loop:

```
result = zeros(5000)
for i = 1:5000
  result(i) = matrix1(i,:)*matrix2(i,:)'
end
```

but is there a way to do this vectorized or with bsxfun?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use element-wise multiplication and sum the rows:

```
result = sum(matrix1.*matrix2, 2);
```